# issues converting into a binary variable

Tags: r, label, character, r-factor

I am trying to convert covidtest_a character to a binary Variable, which will be my dependent variable in my regression. This is as far as I got, the labels are 1,2 for my
resultcovid. I thought it has to be 0,1 or does it matter ?help Studio

```
str(covidtest_a)
chr [1:2810] "No" "Yes" "Yes" "No" "No" "No" "Yes" "No" "No" "Yes" "No" .
```

```
covidtest2<- as.factor(covidtest_a)
resultcovid <-factor(covidtest2, levels = c("No","Yes"), labels = c("No","Yes"))
```

```
str(resultcovid)
 Factor w/ 2 levels "No","Yes": 1 2 2 1 1 1 2 1 1 2 ...
```

```
table(resultcovid)
resultcovid
  No  Yes 
1826  975
```

Comment: It doesn't matter.

Comment: If you really cared, you could do `as.numeric(resultcovid)-1`, which would give you 0 and 1 instead of 1 and 2.